# why 'Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: No module named django' when im trying to install django?

Tags: python, django, pip

So I was trying to install django. I have used `pip3 install django`, and this what happened:
[image: error]

Then i tried to look if my django was having no problem by typing `import django` on python. But this what happened to me:
[image: error]

Can anyone help me? Thanks, it helps me a lot!

Comment: Use `python3` instead of `python`.

Comment: I agree with the above answer, you need to use python3. Your first log is from pip3 and shows that django is installed for python 3.8, however in your second log you are running python 2.7.16

Comment: yes, thats right. i got a little confused why there's 2 version of python in mine while im just installing one version of python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed Django for python 3. When you type `python` in the terminal you opening python 2.7(you can see that in terminal), so try `python3` instead.

Comment: oohh i see. thank you so much for your answers!